# tkinter Combobox: select item and load associated integer value

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, combobox

I'm trying to make a Combobox that returns an integer value when an item is selected. For example, upon selecting an item from the dropdown list, the price of the item is returned.

Ideally, I would like the Combobox input to be load from a single csv file to enable the items and prices to be easily updated.

The code below populates the Combobox with items from a csv file and returns the item selected. But I don't know how to add a new column in the file for the integer values (eg price) associated with each item, or return this integer value when the item is selected.

The code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

def ShowPrice():
    choice = Combobox1.get()
    print(choice)

Box1 = []
with open('File1.csv') as inFile:
    Box1 = [line for line in inFile]

root = tkinter.Tk()

Label1 = tkinter.Label(root, text='Choose item')
Label1.grid()

Combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(root, state='readonly')
Combobox1['values'] = tuple(Box1)
Combobox1.grid()

Button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text='OK', command=ShowPrice)
Button1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

The contents of `File1.csv`:

```
Option1
Option2
Option3
```

Many thanks

Comment: Use a `dict` to create key value pairs when you load the CSV.